# asp.net mvc Add ModelState error using IValidatableObject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, ivalidatableobject

I saw [this nice blog](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1) that describes adding conditional validation to a asp.net mvc viewmodel.  However I'm not sure how the validation error is added/bound to the specific model's property. I would like the error message to be added to my normal ModelState object so I could show the error like so in my view:

```
ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
```

I think if I had access the the ModelState object from the ValidateMethod(..) then I could just do:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("FirstName", "First name is required");
```

And everthing would work smoothly.  I'm trying to add conditional Validation.

Has anyone done this before that could provide some insight? I tried the code in the blog but it seems incomplete.

Thanks!

Comment: Using `IValidatableObject` is only ever going to give you server side validation (no client side validation) so I suggest you consider using conditional validation attributes (but you have not indicated in your question what validation your trying to perform)

Comment: And in the example your linked to, the `ModelState` error is added automatically.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, how is the error linked to the specific propertly? It's not working for me.

Comment: You have not shown your code - I'm not psychic :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I used the same code that was used in the blog. The validate() was triggered. but like I said I'm not sure how his generic error message is added to the specific field on the page.

Comment: It will be displayed in your `@Html.ValidationSummary()` in the view. If you want it to be associated with a specific property then you need to use `yield return new ValidationResult(".....", new[]{ "Property1" });` (but as I noted, this will not give client side validation, only server side)

Comment: It sounds as if you want a `[RequiredIf]` attribute (i.e. required based on the value of another property), but can really help further until you show your code, and explain what your trying to validate

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Thanks! ValidationResult(".....", new[]{ "Property1" }) worked.  That was what the blog was missing. I can't believe I missed that overload.  Good point with the [RequireIf].  If you add that as an answer I can accept it and give you credit.  Cheers.

Comment: Cant give an answer because you have not explained what you trying to validate, or what code you have tried :)

Comment: ..I give up :).

Comment: Do you not understand the purpose of this site? It to provide a resource for helping other users to find solutions to their problems. you question helps no one - it does not adequately explain what you trying to do, and does not contain relevant code!

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use an this overload that was missing from the blog as mentioned by Stephen.:

```
yield return new ValidationResult(".....", new[]{ "Property1" })
```